# How to markup scientific names in XHTML?

Tags: xhtml

I would like to know the best way to markup scientific names in XHTML. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63752/when-is-the-best-time-to-use-b-and-i-in-lieu-of-strong-and-em-if-ever/64005#64005) says I should use the `<i>` element, which I'm not too in favour of, unless of course, it is the right element to use.

I could use `<span class="scientific">`, but seeing as one of the first uses of HTML was to markup scientific documents, I'd imagine there'd be a better semantic hook for this sort of thing.

Also, is there any element to markup the common name of a scientific name?

Note: It looks like Wikipedia, or at lease [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_eagle) is using `<i>` for scientific nams.

**Edit**: Would the `<dfn>` tag be appropiate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dfn` is for a definition of something.

```
<p>The prefix cardio- means <dfn>of the heart</dfn>.</p>
```

As far as I can see in the [list of HTML 4 elements](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/alist.html) nothing specifically fits the bill. This leaves you with a few options:

```
<span class="scientific">cardio</span>
```

The semantics are added by the class, and so this is probably the most correct way, *technically*. However, it does have the downside that without your CSS, it won't appear different in any way to the surrounding text. Another option might be this: */me prepares to duck for cover*

```
<i class="scientific">cardio</i>
```

Now before I get my head bitten off for using the verboten element, `<i>`, consider that it is no less descriptive than using `<span>`, and even if a stylesheet were missing, you'd still get vaguely the correct formatting. Just make sure you add the `class` attribute.

Comment: Good answer, Nick. Hopefully you don't incur any downvotes from people who see <i> and go urgh! I think I'll go with <i> as it is used by Wikipedia and it seems to fit the bill. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: oh, Wikipedia doesn't use any semantics at all in its markup, so I wouldn't use it as a guide. Click Edit on any page and you'll see why. Rather than get their users to learn the correct classes to use, etc, they go for a very simple markup... one step back from WYSIWYG, really.

Comment: Yeh, and I bet they don't use <ins> or <del> with their revisions?

Comment: Nick, according to http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/deprecated.html it hasn't been deprecated, just has lost it's presentational meaning... it does not mean italicize text anymore...

Comment: It's interesting... most people (including me until recently) though <b> and <i> were deprecated.

Comment: Your example is wrong. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-dfn-element
It should be <p>The prefix <dfn>cardio-</dfn> means of the heart.</p>

Comment: oh that's... well... different to what I had expected. Looks like dfn might actually be the right way to do it!

Answer (score 2):

In (X)HTML5, the [`i` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element) should be used:

> […] such as **a taxonomic designation**, a technical term, an idiomatic phrase or short span of transliterated prose from another language, a thought, or a ship name in Western texts.

I guess "taxonomic designation" matches your case.

Comment: Better late than never :)