# What does stylistically offset mean in HTML5?

Tags: html

I read that the < b > element in HTML 5 is used for *"stylistically offset"* text. What does this exactly mean?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18751545/1960712).

Comment: Note that the HTML5 spec does not use the phrase "stylistically offset" to describe the `<b>` element, although drafts from until 2011 did. It now says "The b element represents a span of text to which attention is being drawn for utilitarian purposes without conveying any extra importance and with no implication of an alternate voice or mood, such as key words in a document abstract, product names in a review, actionable words in interactive text-driven software, or an article lede."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Offset" is meant as in *"make stand out from the rest"*. "Stylistically" is meant as opposed to *semantically*; i.e. the element in question does not have any particularly different *meaning* from the rest, but is being highlighted purely for stylistic purposes.

In short: `<b>` is used to highlight content purely for design reasons. As opposed to other *semantic* tags like `<strong>`, which would, for example, make a screen reader put emphasis on the word while reading.