# Is it semantically correct to use a <b> element to mark up keywords without highlighting them?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have a sentence that includes defining a term in another language. After reading through the W3C [official docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html), I used the following markup to convey meaning:

`<p>The <strong><dfn><i lang="tl">barangay</i></dfn></strong> is the <em>smallest</em> <b class="no-bold">political unit</b> in the <b class="no-bold">Philippines</b>.</p>`

with my understanding from the docs that:

- `<strong>` is for strong importance
- `<dfn>` is for the defining instance
- `<i>` is for technical terms and/or transliterations
- `<em>` is for stress emphasis
- `<b>` is for highlighting keywords without marking them as important

What I am not sure of is if I could use the `<b>` element just to mark certain words and phrases as "keywords", without bringing attention to them (hence why I added `class="no-bold"` to change its appearance using CSS). Would this be correct usage of the element?

Comment: You can use a blank `<a></a>` tag and give it a `name` attribute, (without a `href` attribute set). `<b>` means Bold. It' seems silly to use a tag and nullifying it's primary characteristic.

Comment: @pokeybit *Historically* `<b>` meant bold. It does not now. Per the [HTML 5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/textlevel-semantics.html#the-b-element): "The `<b>` element represents a span of text to which attention is being drawn for utilitarian purposes without conveying any extra importance and with no implication of an alternate voice or mood, such as key words in a document abstract, product names in a review, actionable words in interactive text-driven software, or an article lede."

Comment: @JordanRunning with no default style sheet added, a `<b>` tag implies `font-weight: bold;` so regardless what the HTML 5 specs say, it bolds text.

Comment: "[By default] it bolds text" is a very different assertion than "`<b>` means bold."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Styling doesn’t change the meaning. So if it were appropriate in some context to use `b` with styling (e.g., making it bold), it’s also appropriate in that context to use `b` without any styling.

It’s [conceivable that a user-agent makes use of these `b` elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18765356/1591669), even if you don’t style them or don’t do anything else with them.

An actual example: text browsers (or feed readers etc., i.e., any UA that doesn’t support CSS) might display them in bold by default.

#### `class` name for the `b` element

However, the class name `no-bold` is not ideal, as

- it couples the current styling to the content (you might want to change the styling without also having to change the HTML), and
- it doesn’t describe what the purpose of the `b` element is (not useful for consumers of your markup).

This goes for any element, but the spec explicitly mentions it for the `b` element, too:

> […] authors can use the `class` attribute on the `b` element to identify why the element is being used, so that if the style of a particular use is to be changed at a later date, the author doesn’t have to go through annotating each use.

A more suitable name might be `definition-keyword` or something like that.